# rails 4- where to put user function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a sample app for learning rails 4, and I'm a little confused on where I'm meant to build certain things. For example, I want to check if a user is logged in, and if so, display their account balance in the header (a partial).

Thanks to Michael Hartl's tutorial, I have a function to check a user's login status in the session helper, which is included in the application controller and can therefore be accessed in the partial.

Since the balance is tracked in the `Users` table, do I build a function `get_balance` in the `Users` model? Or should I create a function in the application helper? If I do build it in the application helper, is this auto-included in the application controller, or do I have to include it specifically? If I don't build the function in the model, can I still access the `User` object?

Thanks for your patience with a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your users balance is a column in `Users` table, it is already there for you as a field (most possibly `user.balance`). And yes, this is where you should store it. You might use helpers for stuff that is related to general layout of your application and use combination of partial view and layout to spread it around.

Comment: @Migol-- so I will build a function in the users model then? Will it be accessible from all views via the partial? Thanks

Comment: @user101289 if balance is a column, you don't need `User#get_balance`. You should just create a new method in `ApplicationHelper` called `get_balance`, load current user and return balance.

Comment: ok-- then, as I asked above, does ApplicationHelper need to be included in the application controller to be accessed by a partial?

Comment: Dunno, you need to check it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's already on your table, assuming your user is logged in, you could just call

`current_user.balance`

But it sounds like you want to add onto the data given,

I would suggest perhaps using a Rails decorator for your user model.

Basically a decorator adds an object-oriented layer of presentation logic to your Rails application.

I use the [Draper Gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)